# Unable to produce output for scrapy xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

im an absolute newbie in scrapy and python, and this is my first time asking a StackOverflow question so do bear with me here,

I am attempting to extract the data off a table in a website, that is enclosed in a `<span>` tag. I managed to get the outputs correctly when i used the scrapy shell (the values of the COVID-19 Situation Report Summary Table), but I am unable to replicate the outputs into a json/csv file. I've tried the regular `start_urls` (line 8) , but face the issue of an empty output.

This is my current code , and it is also giving me a blank json output/file without any errors whatsoever

```
import scrapy

class Covid19spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "covid19summary"  # name of spider
  

    def parse(self,response):
        self.start_urls = 'https://www.moh.gov.sg/covid-19/statistics' #url of the website to crawl

        all_data = response.xpath("//td")
        for data in all_data:
            indiv_data = response.xpath("//td/span[1]/text()").extract()
            # print(indiv_data)
            yield {
                'cases': response.xpath("//td/span[1]/text()").extract() 
            }
```

Would appreciate some help on this ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: this is only part of the code, the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Using scrapy:

```
import scrapy

class Covid19spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "covid19summary"  # name of spider
    start_urls = ['https://www.moh.gov.sg/covid-19/statistics'] #url of the website to crawl

    def parse(self,response):
        all_data = response.xpath("//td")
        for data in all_data:
            indiv_data = response.xpath("//td/span[1]/text()").extract()
            # print(indiv_data)
            yield {
            'cases': response.xpath("//td/span[1]/text()").extract() 
            }
```

This works fine.
Try this one

```
import scrapy

class Covid19spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "covid19summary"  # name of spider
    start_urls = ['https://www.moh.gov.sg/covid-19/statistics'] #url of the website to crawl

    def parse(self,response):
        tb_data = response.css("td span::text").extract()
        yield {'data' : tb_data}
```

Notice how this one doesn't give "Date" heading of first table in the webpage and only gives you those elements' inner text having a span tag inside a td tag. So I recommend you read CSS selectors concepts.

Date heading source-code:

```
<td height="20" width="64">
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px;">
    <strong>Date</strong>
    </span>
</td>
```

Other headings :

```
<td width="64" style="text-align: right;">
    <strong>
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px;">Imported</span>
    </strong>
</td>
```

My code give text part of those span tags which are inside td tags,